# Proof of a proposition regarding rings and ideals

Tags: ring-theory

I am looking for a proof of the following proposition:

If A is a principal ideal domain, let the following increasing sequence of Ideals of A: $I_1⊆I_2⊆I_3⊆...⊆I_m⊆...$

Then there exists $n \geq 1$ such that $I_n =I_{n+k}, \forall k \geq 1$

Comment: I'm guessing you mean $I_n=I_{n+k}$?

Comment: yes I've edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I=\cup_{n\geq 1}I_n$, and observe that $I$ is an ideal. (While it is not true in general that the union of a collection of ideals is an ideal, it is true for an ascending union).

Since $A$ is a PID, $I$ can be generated by some element $x$. Let $n$ be the minimal index for which $x\in I_n$, then we have $I_n=I$, hence $I_n=I_{n+k}$ for all $k\geq 0$.